# Android: execute code inside foreground service when button is clicked

Tags: android, android-intent, service, alarm, foreground-service

To my understanding, I can add an action that will present itself as a button to a notification that is built inside of a Service that I start as a Foreground Service with this line:

```
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp, "com.mypackage.ACTION_STOP", pendingIntent);
```

Now, this action is to be received by the `pendingIntent` object which can either contain an activity or the same service class. But what if I simply wanna execute code inside of the same service? My service simply triggers an alarm (that is created inside of the service so I can't access it from another class) that I want to be able to stop once you click on the notification, or on the notification button, or anything. But everything seems so overengineered to the point where is frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

`Pending Intent` is not only about starting an activity. You can build broadcast pending intent and receive an action to handle it as you want.

1. Create Broadcast receiver:

```kotlin
private class NotificationBroadcastReceiver(
    private val onActionClick: () -> Unit
) : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        when (intent.action) {
            YOUR_ACTION -> onActionClick()
            else -> Log.d("$javaClass", "Unknown notification action: ${intent.action}")
        }
    }
}
```

2. Register receiver:

```kotlin
context.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(YOUR_ACTION))
```

3. Create broadcast intent:

```kotlin
private fun createBroadcastIntent(): PendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,
        REQUEST_CODE,
        Intent(YOUR_ACTION).setPackage(context.packageName),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
```

4. Add action when you build your notification:

```kotlin
builder.addAction(
    NotificationCompat.Action(
        R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp,
        context.getString(R.string.action_description),
        createBroadcastIntent()
    )
)
```